# Consulta Base de Datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla de movimientos bancarios de muchos usuarios que se pueden repetir a lo largo de la misma. La tabla tiene distintos campos como Caja, NombreUsuario, Dni, Fecha, Importe...

Lo que quiero hacer es un ranking de cajas con más usuarios ordenados por el dni (sin estar repetido). Es decir tengo:

```
Alberto - caja1 - dni1 - fecha1 - importe1
David - caja2 - dni2 - fecha2 - importe2
Carlos - caja3 - dni3 - fecha3 - importe3
Miguel - caja1 - dni4 - fecha4 - importe4
Roberto - caja2 - dni5 - fecha5 - importe5
Luis - caja3 - dni6 - fecha6 - importe6
Nacho - caja1 - dni7 - fecha7 - importe7
Alberto - caja1 - dni1 - fecha8 - importe8
```

Y lo que quiero es que aparezca:

```
Caja1 - 3
Caja2 - 2
Caja3 - 2
```

Lo que ya tengo hecho es:

```
SELECT Caja, COUNT(DISTINCT dni) as Usuarios
FROM miTabla
GROUP BY Caja
```

Pero esto me saca todas las cajas con sus respectivos usuarios y no las que más usuarios tienen.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Deberías mostrar lo que has intentado, tal y como has formulado la pregunta parece que quieres que te hagan la tarea.

Comment: Sí perdón, a la hora de pasarlo no me he acordado de ponerlo!

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la salida que te da? Según las pruebas que he hecho debe darte la salida esperada.

Comment: En la salida me aparece cada caja con sus distintos usuarios que han hecho movimientos. Hasta ahí bien, pero me salen todas las cajas, y necesito las que más usuarios tengan.

Comment: Te he escrito una respuesta, si no es lo que necesitas exactamente pon un comentario y dime ;)

Comment: Esa consulta te saca el número de usuarios en cada caja, el rankig lo haces tu. Si quieres puedes hacer un ORDER BY  Usuarios DESC y te ordenara las cajas de mayor a menor número de usuarios. Y si quieres un limite de le pones un LIMIT

Comment: Justo! Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que te estoy entendiendo, si lo que quieres es que te muestre el número de usuarios distintos que han utilizado cada caja la consulta sería la que tú tienes.

Pero si lo que quieres es que independientemente de si un usuario ha utilizado dos o más veces una caja, muestre todos los usuarios que han utilizado cada una la consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT Caja, COUNT(dni) as Usuarios
FROM calc
GROUP BY Caja
```

Es decir, sin el distinct. También te valdría la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT Caja, COUNT(*) as Usuarios
FROM calc
GROUP BY Caja
```

La salida de estas consultas es esta:

> caja1 - 4
>
> caja2 - 2
>
> caja3 - 2

Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es que únicamente te muestre la caja que más usuarios ha tenido la consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT Caja, COUNT(*) as Usuarios
FROM calc
GROUP BY Caja
order by COUNT(*) desc
limit 1
```

La salida de esta consulta es esta:

> caja1 - 4

Comment: Justo lo iba sacando yo también, pero lo del limit me ha dado la vida! Muchas gracias!!